# Does mysql query cache have to be off to use memcached?

Tags: mysql, memcached

How do you know if `memcached` is being used? Server has `mysql query cache` on and I believe it also has memcahced installed, but how do I know if memcached is being used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

memcache and sql query cache are independent of each other and both can be used without impacting each other. memcache needs to be installed as a separate server process and cache needs to be managed programatically.

1. Check if memcache is listening on the port on which it was installed:

netstat -ap | grep selected_port

If it is listening on that port, means it has started

2. To check if it is setting the cache or getting from cache, you start in verbose mode manually (use the following command) and observe for sometime for any data being cached or not:

memcached -vv

Answer (score 4):

memcached has its own [status screen](http://livebookmark.net/journal/wp-content/uploads/2008/05/memcache.png) where you can see all kind of information about it. You can also see memcached stats from command line with `echo stats | nc localhost 11211` (just replace `localhost` and `11211` with your memcached server and the port memcached is listening at).

Answer (score 3):

Memcached will be used if some component of your application stack has been configured to use it.  The MySQL query cache is completely unrelated to memcached.